# Extracting a matrix from a cell vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

> A sparse matrix is a large matrix with almost all elements of the same
> value (typically zero). The normal representation of a sparse matrix
> takes up lots of memory when the useful information can be captured
> with much less. A possible way to represent a sparse matrix is with a
> cell vector whose first element is a 2-element vector representing the
> size of the sparse matrix. The second element is a scalar specifying
> the default value of the sparse matrix. Each successive element of the
> cell vector is a 3-element vector representing one element of the
> sparse matrix that has a value other than the default. The three
> elements are the row index, the column index and the actual value.
> Write a function called "sparse2matrix" that takes a single input of a
> cell vector as defined above and returns the output argument called
> "matrix", the matrix in its traditional form. Consider the following
> run:

cellvec = {[2 3], 0, [1 2 3], [2 2 -3]};

matrix = sparse2matrix(cellvec)

matrix =

```
 0      3      0
 0     -3      0
```

Good morning/afternoon/night, everyone

I was wondering if you could help me with this.

I am trying to complete this, but I am not sure how to deal with this. I understand that I am interested in the first part of the cell vector, but I am not sure about how to tell Matlab I need that. This is my code:

```
function matrix = sparse2matrix(x)

A = [2 3];
B = 0;
C = [1, 2, 3];

x = {A, 0, C};

matrix = cell2mat(x);

end
```

The result of this code is different from the result I showed above.
I am not getting the right answer and honestly I do not know what to do, so I would appreciate if you guide me a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant way of doing it but it gets the job done. Uses the `cell2mat()` function and indexing to grab the necessary values for each step. A for-loop is then used to obtain the 3-element vectors that is used to change the array values from the default values in the respective indices.

```
cellvec = {[2 3], 0, [1 2 3], [2 2 -3]};

[matrix] = sparse2matrix(cellvec)


function [matrix] = sparse2matrix(x)
Matrix_Size = cell2mat(x(1,1));
Matrix_Height = Matrix_Size(1);
Matrix_Width = Matrix_Size(2);

Default_Value = cell2mat(x(1,2));
matrix = Default_Value*ones(Matrix_Height,Matrix_Width);

Triplets = x(3:end);
Number_Of_Triplets = length(Triplets);

for Triplet_Index = 1: Number_Of_Triplets
    
    Current_Triplet = cell2mat(Triplets(1,Triplet_Index));
    Row = Current_Triplet(1,1);
    Column = Current_Triplet(1,2);
    Value = Current_Triplet(1,3);
    matrix(Row,Column) = Value;
    
end
end
```

---

### Explanation:

[image: Cell Array in Workspace]

The first line in the local function `sparse2matrix()` indicates to retrieve row 1, column 1 of the cell array `x` and then convert it to a matrix. The conversion is done using the `cell2mat()` function.

```
Matrix_Size = cell2mat(x(1,1));
```

**Results in:**

> Matrix_Size = [2 3]

---

The following line indicates to grab index 1 of the previous array `Matrix_Size`. This will be used to determine the height of the output array `matrix`. This is done in a similar fashion to evaluate the `Matrix_Width` using index 2.

```
Matrix_Height = Matrix_Size(1);
```

**Results in:**

> Matrix_Height = 2

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering me! I was losing hope, but now I feel a little better because someone help me. However, could I ask a question? I am not too familiar with everything you used here and I want to understand. For example, it is not clear to me what is the meaning of  cell2mat(x(1,1))... Would it be possible to explain what are these 1,1? You do not have to answer, obviously, maybe it is a silly question for you, but in the case you want to, I look forward to your response. I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: I added a little explanation hopefully this clears up the first two lines of the code.